# MATLAB logical indexing: Is a(find(b<1)) = 0, the same as a(b(b<1)) = 0?

Tags: matlab, indexing

As my question suggests, my goal is to find all the indices of the values in b less than 1, and set these same indices in a to zero.

The first expression i.e.

```
a(find(b<1)) = 0
```

does what I want, but matlab is suggesting that I use logical indices to improve performance. Does the second expression do the same thing?

```
a(b(b<1)) = 0
```

Comment: @RopertP I take your point. However if people are happy to answer and moreover offer clarification, then I have some trouble understanding what the problem is. Not trying to be incorrigible with the latter point. If you, or anybody, would like to explain the greater importance of your point in more detail, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

```
a(b<1) = 0
```

does the same thing.

```
b(b<1)
```

returns the values of `b` where `b` is smaller than 1.
This is not a logical value (which it should be for logical indexing) and it is probably not of the same size as `b` (unless *all* values are less than 1).

Comment: I hope it's OK I made a minor edit to your answer..? If not, there is a rollback function you can use.

Comment: @RobertP. Seems like editing it was a good thing to do - got distracted somewhere I'm afraid :>

Answer (score 1):

`find` returns the actual indices of elements values are less than a 1. on the other hand, `b<1` returns vector with length equal to b and it has 0's for elements fulfill the condition and 1's for those does not fill fill condition.
Let suppose, you have b vector:

```
b = [2 3 4 5 6 -1 9 -2]
find(b<2)
ans =

     6     8
>> b<2

ans =

     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1
 b(b<2)

ans =

    -1    -2
a(b(b<1)) =0
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

So both operations are not same. `b<1`returns the logical array and `find(b)` returns the indices of elements fulfill condition.